# Using Customizable list in a Website created in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, html, aspx, powerapp

***Current Scenario :***

- I have uploaded few aspx files into my sharepoint online and it is pretty much static and is being used as department Website
- Using a list from sharepoint to store and process data received from users through powerapps (here powerapps is used for better UI/validations etc)

***Required Setup :***

- The list that is being currently used should be somehow managed to fit in the static site and users should be allowed to create entries directly (without using powerapps),also here the list interface/page should be highly customizable ,so as to enable user,data validation/authentication etc
- We dont have proper license to use powerapps,we are using it by extending the trial,hence need to stop using it asap

Request you all to please help with the above mentioned requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you do not to pay for PowerApps, you can only use css or SPFX to customize the sharepoint list with custom actions/buttons.

For customizing your list forms, PowerApps/InfoPath shall be the only option for you. You can do column validation inside SharePoint list: https://www.sharepointsky.com/sharepoint-online-list-column-validation-examples/